# Can MLCC still crack even if it is used within recommended operating conditions?

Tags: mlcc

I am trying to understand what causes cracking in MLCC. So one cause is that there is shear stress on the MLCC due to how it is soldered onto the PCB. This will eventually cause mechanical failure. Another is the PCB flexing which also puts shear force on the MLCC and can cause component to fail.

Can MLCC still fail by cracking if it is operated within the limits defined by the manufacturer? This is to say that the applied voltage, current, and temperature applied to the component is within the limits specified by the manufacturer.

Comment: There is a misconception: a static stress need not cause failure. Crack formation is typically acute and immediate. (A good question is: whether barium titanate and relatives exhibit such deformation mechanisms, or creep or etc.) Stress may predispose an element to failure when further loaded in the same direction, but that additional loading (e.g. vibration) would be better considered the cause. Whether you mean "eventual" to include vibration, is not clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience, the major cause of MLCC cracking is impact/scraping damage due to poor handling of the assembled PCB.  This is followed by incorrect thermal profile during reflow, in particular the cooldown phase. Finally there is flexing of the PCB post-production. (So a slight superset of the causes you call out in your question.)

I've never seen one fail due to electrical abuse.  Not to say it can't, just I've never seen it.

Tantalum capacitors are a different matter, and even relatively mild overvoltage can cause total failure (normally a "burst" not a crack).

Comment: The one certainty with any physical device is that one day it will stop working.  That said, the MTBF for an MLCC is likely in the tens of millions of hours.  Personally I’ve seen many failed capacitors but none of these have occurred without evidence of mechanical damage.  Although I have seen MLCC’s capacitance drop slightly with age.

Comment: Agree.  I've designed safety critical telecoms kit, and have been deeply involved in reliability analysis.  With midplanes (which have to keep working as they can't be replaced), the MLCCs are way up the reliability scale, and critically fail safe.  If we have a good degree of decoupling redundancy (including headroom for aging), all is good.  Tantalum caps on the other hand are a) more susceptible to overvoltage/transient failure b) can fail short-circuit.  We were therefore forced to use extra expensive units which have built in fuses.